# WCF programmatically set endpoint address: No elements matching the key were found in the configuration element collection

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I'm performing what I believed was a pretty basic task.  We have an environment with multiple servers (DEV, TEST, PRODUCTION) and I'd like to programmatically change the service endpoint.  To do this I am creating a new `EndPointAddress` and instantiating the client as:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding("BasicHttpBinding_IMyService");
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://domain.name/myservice.svc"));
MyService.MyServiceClient client = new MyService.MyServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
```

I am receiving the following error.

`No elements matching the key 'BasicHttpBinding_IMyService' were found in the configuration element collection.`

I have included my app.config below but, as you can see, I do have the binding defined.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" >
               <... removed directives for ease of reading ...>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://domain.name/MyService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService"
            contract="MyService.IMyService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm sorry if this is a simple question but I haven't been able to identify the problem.  I'll call it the 'late-Friday brain fog', and maybe you can call it 'easy points'?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of VS are you using? This is something we would typically handle through config file transforms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindings in the Web.config of the WCF application and the app.config of the client application must match

Comment: The app.config I posted is from the client-side and was generated via svcutil.exe. Strange they don't match enough to be supported. Is it enough to copy the service section from the web.config and place it in the app.config?

Comment: Not exactly, the bindings between the two match closely except for some settings that are set in each config.  This is a pretty in depth article on bindings and how they work in the config files http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx